# Not able to change the image color of the image view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fastadapter

I need some help here. I am fetching the data from the JSON.Fetching data. It consists of images and text and I am using the Fast Adapter(mike penz) to populate into recycler view, but when I select the specified row from the recycler view, it needs to change the image color. Where can I change the text view color by using the selector but I can't change the color of the image in the image view of the selected row. Please help me out. Here is the code:

```
service_type_adapter.withOnClickListener(new FastAdapter.OnClickListener<Service_Type_Adapter>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClick(View v, IAdapter<Service_Type_Adapter> adapter, Service_Type_Adapter item, int position) {
                AppCompatImageView service_image= (AppCompatImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.service_image);
                int service_imagecolors = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.skyblue);
                service_image.setColorFilter(service_imagecolors, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                service_type_adapter.select(position);
                if (lastselectedposition != -1) {
                    service_type_adapter.deselect(lastselectedposition);
                }
                lastselectedposition = position;
                servicetypename = item.getServicename();
                action = item.getServiceid();
                googlemap.clear();
                onMapReady(googlemap);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter)'s `OnClickListener` already provides you everything you need. It passes the clicked item, and also the `Adapter` responsible for the specific item.

So when the user clicks on the item (and you have enabled selection for that item) the `FastAdapter` will automatically set the `state` of that item to selected.

There are multiple ways of automatically applying the color in that case:

1. Use [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html)

The easiest solution is to define a `ColorStateList` instead of a simple color for that item. For example you could have a `Foreground` and just define a translucent color if the state is selected. 
A very simple `ColorStateList` could look like this:

```
return new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected},
                        new int[]{}
                },
                new int[] {
                        colorSelected,
                        Color.TRANSPARENT
                }
        );
```

2. [Automatically Notify](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/library-core/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/FastAdapter.java#L213) the `Adapter` about the change

The `FastAdapter` allows you to enable the `bindView` being called in case of the selection. Enable this via: `FastAdapter.withSelectWithItemUpdate(true)` After this the `bindView` method of that element is called and you can simply check for `isSelected` and define the `ColorFilter` or not

3. Notify the `Adapter` manually

If the adapter should not automatically call the `notify` method you can do this on your own also by doing `fastAdapter.notifyAdapterItemChanged(position)` (you can optional pass a [payload](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)) in addition, so you can check for that one in the `bindView` method) after that check again in the `bindView` method for `isSelected` or not and handle the UI as you need it

Comment: Sir Can you please provide me an example ?

Comment: About what exactly?

Comment: About fastAdapter.notifyAdapterItemChanged(position) i had tried it but there is not effect on it sir

Comment: you have to check inside your `bindView` and handle that selected state properly